# Reload page if stored Text is a certain value using Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am using `storeText | css=strong | k`

to pull a value from my webpage.

If the value put in `'k'` is `"reload"` I want to refresh the page.

Which function in selenium IDE can accomplish this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First check what the value is in `k` , then you can use

```
refresh
```

or probably

```
refreshAndWait
```

for page refresh.

Source : http://seleniummaster.com/sitecontent/index.php/introduction-to-selenium-automation/selenium-ide/114-selenium-ide-complete-list-of-commands

Comment: how do I check the value of k and use logic to refresh?  I know how to refresh

Comment: You'll need to install a flow control plugin to help with the flow.
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flow-control/

You can read more about it here : http://51elliot.blogspot.in/2008/02/selenium-ide-goto.html